# How can I play Ingress while in China?

Tags: ingress

I read that Google Servers are restricted from DNS in China. What is the best and safest way to play ingress with a local Chinese mobile operator? I see 2 options
1-Change host file on my rooted Android device
2-VPN

I am not sure if Google checks the source ip of the country and the actual location from GPS and ban users. If there is no such control I will go with VPN. I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this.

Comment: This strays into bypassing protections territory.  If Google doesn't allow you to play Ingress in China, I'm not sure we should be helping you do exactly that.

Comment: I see where you are coming from. I am just trying to find out correct information. Maybe Ingress app is not even banned in China and only Google is. It is not wrong to "not know" it is however wrong to "not try to learn".

Comment: Considering the kind of game that Ingress is, I would imagine there wouldn't be much community support in China if it is generally blocked there. [This article](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NRKDLQMXrY8PmSuAEuN5I7FUv4pgeIA6OjtSkJyUBxU/preview) as well as others I can find appear to support the idea that Ingress can be played. All methods that I can find which sound plausible to me require rooting your phone.

Comment: Also I would consider changing your question. *best* and *safest* are both opinion-based and will get many different opinion-based answers which is against the rules of this site. Consider asking a more straight-forward answer such as "How can I play Ingress while in China?" will get you better results.

Answer (score 13):

I am a Chinese citizen playing ingress.

Google services are restricted in China, modifying the host file might be a solution but I have not tried because this way doesn't last long. The Great Firewall sometimes blocks Google IPs directly.

VPN is much easier and you don't need to root you device. Many friends of mine are playing this game by VPN or shadowsocks. Google has not banned us for this reason so far. I think Google knows what's going on here.

Answer (score 2):

Roaming worked for me. It looks like that most restrictions are not applied to foreign users in the country.

My device is using a German sim card (Deutsche Telekom) and I had no problems playing Ingress in China.

The moment I switched to Wifi (like the hotel Wifi, or in the office), it stopped working.